# Не могу понять почему не работает, когда использую другой класс?

Tags: swift

Не могу понять, почему когда делаю класс наследник. Все перестает работать:
Когда делаю вторую таблицу через Table2 он не показывает таблицу. Как исправить?
Или может кто подскажет, как можно сделать через анонимные классы?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
@IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var tabl2: UITableView!

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10;
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // пытается загрузить ранее созданую ячейку из памяти
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyTableViewCell")
    // если она не создавалась ранее
    if cell == nil {
        // то генерируем новую
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "MyTableViewCell")
    }
    // устанавливем необходимый текст в строке таблицы
    cell?.textLabel?.text = "Точки №\(indexPath.row)!"
    return cell!
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let tablHelp = Table2()
    table.dataSource = self
    table.delegate = self

    tabl2.dataSource = tablHelp
    tabl2.delegate = tablHelp
}
func tableView2(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10;
}
}

class Table2: NSObject, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10;
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // пытается загрузить ранее созданую ячейку из памяти
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyTableViewCell")
    // если она не создавалась ранее
    if cell == nil {
        // то генерируем новую
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "MyTableViewCell")
    }
    // устанавливем необходимый текст в строке таблицы
    cell?.textLabel?.text = "Точки №\(indexPath.row)!"
    return cell!
}
```

}

Comment: Опишите какую конечную цель вы пытаетесь достичь? Зачем вам наследование UITableView

Comment: @ВикторМишустин, Я пытаюсь, чтобы на одном экране были 2 таблицы. Для этого я создал 2 класс Table2. И унаследовался от UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource. Но почему то вторая таблица не заполняется(

Comment: Просто какой смысл несет наследование делегата и дата сорса, почему не создать вторую таблицу?

Comment: @ВикторМишустин, Потому что не получается создать нормальный делегат в переменной. Приходится делать через класс. Может посоветуете что-нибудь?

Comment: каждый метод delegate и datasource хранит в себе ссылку на tableView которому он принадлежит. Вы можете сравнивать этот объект с вашим объектом из outlet. И создавать необходимые вам условия в зависимости от этого.

Answer (score 0):

Вынесите переменную tablHelp из функции:

```
@IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var tabl2: UITableView!

let tablHelp = Table2()
```

Comment: Изменил, но все равно не получается

Comment: Я даже унаследовался от котроллера. То все равно не пишет.

Comment: а что значит не получается? ошибку какую-то выдает?

Comment: Ошибки, то нету. Просто не отсутствует таблица. И я не могу понять почему